Trouble deploying Django app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk
I'm having the following issues when running eb deploy:
2024/04/29 18:00:10 [warn] 28747#28747: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size
Apr 29 18:00:15 ip-172-31-85-53 web[28824]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'authentication'
authentication is a Django app.
These are the two main errors found from the logs provided after updating the environment from eb deploy.
I'm following this tutorial I found: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-elastic-beanstalk/
I've had to change a couple things obviously due to different project structure/details but I'm not understanding why these errors are coming up. I have not yet set up AWS RDS for PSQL, but I plan on doing that once I fix these errors. I am also using React as a frontend but I have not yet configured the environment for that either.
Here are some of my config files:
# .ebextensions/01_django.config

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "campusconnect.campusconnect.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "campusconnect.campusconnect.wsgi:application"

# .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml
branch-defaults:
  aws-psql:
    environment: SE-Dev-Project-dev
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: SE-Dev_Project
  branch: null
  default_platform: Python 3.11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application

And my project structure:
.
├── .ebextensions
│    ├── 01_django.config
├── .elasticbeanstalk
│    ├── config.yml
├── campusconnect
│   ├── authentication
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── campusconnect
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── management
│   │   │   └── commands
│   │   │       └── createsu.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── clubs
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── event
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── frontend
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   │   ├── assets
│   │   │   │   ├── CampusConnectLogo-Dg1hByEv.svg
│   │   │   │   ├── index-CVnlfLJY.js
│   │   │   │   ├── index-HOqmfudM.css
│   │   │   │   └── RampartOne-Regular-Cy2W9s50.ttf
│   │   │   ├── index.html
│   │   │   └── vite.svg
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── package-lock.json
│   │   ├── postcss.config.js
│   │   ├── public
│   │   │   └── vite.svg
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   ├── assets
│   │   │   │   ├── CampusConnectLogo.svg
│   │   │   │   ├── pngtree-pencil-icon-png-image_1753753.jpg
│   │   │   │   ├── RampartOne-Regular.ttf
│   │   │   │   └── react.svg
│   │   │   ├── components
│   │   │   │   ├── App.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── Club
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ClubApplication.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ClubPage.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   └── Members.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── Comments
│   │   │   │   │   └── CommentElement.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── Events
│   │   │   │   │   ├── CreateEvent.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   └── EventElement.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── Functions
│   │   │   │   │   └── convertDate.ts
│   │   │   │   ├── LandingPage
│   │   │   │   │   ├── Calendar.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   ├── Explore.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   ├── LandingPage.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   ├── MyClubs.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   ├── NavBar.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   └── Newsletter.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── Login.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── Posts
│   │   │   │   │   ├── CreatePost.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   ├── DeletePost.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   ├── EditPost.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   ├── PostElement.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   └── PostPage.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── Profile
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ProfileSettings.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   └── Profile.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── Register.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── UI
│   │   │   │   │   ├── CustomPaletteOptions.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   └── FormElement.tsx
│   │   │   │   ├── Utils
│   │   │   │   │   ├── LoadingIndicator.tsx
│   │   │   │   │   └── ProtectedRoute.tsx
│   │   │   │   └── VerifyEmail.tsx
│   │   │   ├── index.css
│   │   │   ├── main.tsx
│   │   │   └── vite-env.d.ts
│   │   ├── tailwind.config.js
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.node.json
│   │   └── vite.config.ts
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── media
│   │   ├── clubs
│   │   ├── images
│   │   └── prof
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── posts
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── prof
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── migrations
│       │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│       │   └── __init__.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── serializers.py
│       ├── tests.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── views.py
├── Dockerfile
├── output.txt
├── README.md
└── requirements.txt

I have attempted to completely delete the environment and make a new one, but I seem to be getting the same issues. Also tried rebooting, etc...

I think you might need to eb init inside campusconnect. You would need to move your .ebextensions directory inside campusconnect too.

Would requirements.txt need to be moved into campusconnect as well then?

Please ignore my previous comment. See my answer below.

Your project structure is fine. The issue is actually with your WSGI_PATH. Change
  ...
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "campusconnect.campusconnect.wsgi:application"

to
  ...
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "campusconnect.wsgi:application"

